# How can I remotely inspect the data in my RedisCloud DBs?

Tags: ruby, heroku, redis

I'm using Heroku to host a simple Ruby on Rails test app to learn how to use Redis. I'm using RedisCloud as my Redis servis provider. Locally, I can inspect my Redis DBs using the Redis CLI, but how can I inspect the data in the RedisCloud DBs that my Heroku app is using?

RedisCloud provides a dashboard that shows stats, but not the actual data. Also, I've tried using the [Redis Desktop Manager](http://redisdesktop.com/) software, but it has too many bugs to allow me to remotely connect to my RedisCloud DBs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Step by step:

1 - Check your Heroku config, in order to find out the REDIS URL.

```
heroku config
```

You should see an entrance that look like this:

```
REDISCLOUD_URL:              redis://rediscloud:foobarfoobarfoobar@a-redis-address:18888
```

2 - Connect to your remote Redis DB using `redis-cli`:

```
redis-cli -h a-redis-address -p 18888 -a foobarfoobarfoobar
```

You should be able to query your Redis DB now.

Comment: Since you're already in the cloud, I recommend that you check out Redsmin (http://redsmin.com) - a lot of our users find it invaluable :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Rails you can also connect to the Rails console like this:

```
$ heroku run console
```

Once connected, you will have an initialized redis connection based on your configuration (eg. you have `$redis = Redis.new(url: ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"])` in your `config/initializers/redis.rb`):

```
irb(main):001:0> $redis
=> #<Redis client v3.2.1 for redis://domain.com/0>
```

Alternatively, you can make a new one:

```
irb(main):002:0> $redis2 = Redis.new(url: 'redis://domain.com')
irb(main):003:0> $redis2
=> #<Redis client v3.2.1 for redis://domain.com/0>
```