# How to remotely inspect data with Heroku / RedisCloud / Node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis, node-redis

I have RedisCloud running with Node.js on Heroku and would like to inspect data remotely, ideally using the command line in OS X. I've seen this:

[How can I remotely inspect the data in my RedisCloud DBs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021920/how-can-i-remotely-inspect-the-data-in-my-rediscloud-dbs)

but it is for Ruby and doesn't work for me.  (I get ***redis-cli: command not found***.)

I'm using the node_redis client:

https://github.com/mranney/node_redis

The requires in my server app look like this:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
http = require('http'),
server = http.createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
redis = require('redis'),
ioredis = require('socket.io-redis'),
url = require('url'),
redisURL = url.parse(process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`redis-cli` isn't a Ruby tool, it is a standard part of the Redis package. The easiest way of getting on your Mac is to download and build Redis from https://github.com/antirez/redis. Once you've done that, your laptop will be able to use the compiled binary.

Note that when in a bind and in need of connecting to Redis, you can also use plain telnet.